# How to use a realm having an ActiveDirectoryAuthenticator provider for a webapp deployed in weblogic?

Tags: java, active-directory, weblogic

I am new to weblogic and I am trying to use some LDAP authentication in my webapp by using an the ActiveDirectoryAuthenticator configured in a security realm. I looked over some tutorial, but I cannot access that LDAP authenticator from my app to login my users from java. Does anyone know a tutorial or how can I succeed this, please?

I tried already a form authentication as I found in oracle docs.

I defined a login confing in my web.xml

```
<login-config>
<auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
<realm-name>ADMSC</realm-name>
<form-login-config>
    <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>
    <form-error-page>/error.jsp</form-error-page>
</form-login-config>
```

I defined the security role for the given users:

```
<security-role>
    <role-name>TEST</role-name>
</security-role>
```

I  defined some security constraints for my urls:

```
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>Protect secure pages</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>secure</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/none/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>TEST</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

I defined a gorup, in weblogic.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.9/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
<wls:container-descriptor>
    <wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>true</wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>
</wls:container-descriptor>
<wls:security-role-assignment>
    <wls:role-name>TEST</wls:role-name>
    <wls:principal-name>PSWUsers</wls:principal-name>
</wls:security-role-assignment>
```

I have a basic login form:

```
<form action="j_security_check" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="j_username" />
    <input type="secret" name="j_password" />
    <input type="submit">Login in</input>
</form>
```

And I get a 403. The ActiveDirectoryAuthenticator configured in my realm does say it could access AD successfully. The issue is in my configs. What I I doing wrong?

Comment: Post also the weblogic.xml file to check the mapping between roles and principals.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the post with weblogic.xml.

Comment: Are you sure that the authenticated user belongs to PSWUsers ?

Comment: After trying to make some simple weblogic login, I managed to authenticate by using some simple users that I created inside weblogic. I also managed to retrieve the users from LDAP with an ActiveDirectoryAuthenticator, but there might be some problem regarding the users group: PSWUsers. In LDAP, when I authenticate with some admin user I get that my test users belong to: CN=PSWUsers,OU=Test,OU=SOMEOU[other configs I cannot make public]. I assumed that PSWUsers is the group of the users as thei have the value memberOf = PSWUsers

Comment: Is the AD Provider configured correctly inside the realm? As in, can it access the user and the group it belongs to within the AD? If you have access to the WebLogic /console GUI, you could check this easily.